# Running Jest in both development and production

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, jestjs

Is there a way to run Jest in development and production, and then merge its coverage results?

I used to do that with nyc + mocha/ava, collecting the JSON files resulting from both test runs, but this seems not to work with the JSON files from Jest.

Any idea?

Comment: Out of interest why do you want to do this?

Comment: Quite often you have code that runs only in dev/production, and want to know your overall test coverage. In the end, I managed to do it in macOS, but oddly not in Windows

Comment: I made it with jest and nyc compiling the results at the end